# isolated php issue in embedded constructors

Tags: php

I have php:

```
public function __construct($config) {
    if (!session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
    parent::__construct(Array $config) { // line no 52 
      if (!empty($config['sharedSession'])) {
        $this->initSharedSession();
      }
   }
 }
```

I get an eror that says line 52 should be a `T_VARIABLE`.  I've given up.  what do i do.

Comment: What's that supposed to be? A method call or a method declaration? Currently it's trying to be both, which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: shouldnt it be `$config = array()`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? Are you trying to override the parent constructor because you think it will execute whether you call it or not? (It only gets executed if you call parent::__constructor(); in the new constructor.)

Comment: This is either fundamental lack of knowledge about language's syntax or you're probably overworked and need a break in order to see the mistake you've done.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "embedded constructors" in PHP. The code you show is simply invalid nonsense, plain and simple. I'm not sure what other language you come from or what expectations you have in PHP, but it simply doesn't do whatever you're trying to do there.

To clarify how *overriding methods* works, because that seems to be what you're trying to do:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct($value) {
        echo $value;
    }

}


class Bar extends Foo {

    public function __construct($value) {
        echo $value . ' Bar';
    }

}


class Baz extends Foo {

    public function __construct($value) {
        echo $value . ' Baz';
        parent::__construct($value);
    }

}

new Foo(42);  // 42
new Bar(42);  // 42Bar
new Baz(42);  // 42Baz42
```

To override a method in a child class, you simply implement a method of the same name in the child. The parent's method of the same name is thereby overridden and does not get executed anymore. You can *call* the parent's implementation of the method using `parent::methodName()`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

```
parent::__construct(Array $config) {
    if (!empty($config['sharedSession'])) {
       $this->initSharedSession();
    }
}
```

You can't call parent constructor like this. You have to modify your code

```
parent::__construct(Array $config);
```

Comment: @deceze Can you please tell me why not work?